# Rails project not found spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb, where can create it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading ruby and rails tutorial 2nd edition book.

I am facing problem to do dynamic title in title pages. 
In this book write done this path "spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" and i have not found any spec folder in rails project where it is located ? where can create a static_pages_spec.rb file ?

I am using rails 4.0.2

book link :http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top

Listing 4.4. Updated tests for the Home page’s title.
spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

please help me

```
path "spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb "
```

May i create it spec folder in rails root folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder spec located in rails root dir.

in Rails you can use Rspec generator or create helper:

add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

run rails generator:

```
rails g rspec:install
```

This create folder `spec` in you project and generate `spec_helper.rb`

And run `rspec` or `bundle exec rspec`.

Comment: after install run this "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" after this "rails generate integrateion_test static_pages" for others helps

Comment: Hi I am facing one problem now, Bundle is install gem is also install now when i run this command "jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:~/rails_project$ rails generate integration test static_pages" error is comming please help me "Could not find generator integration."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156881/rspec-gem-install-and-run-this-script-geting-error

Answer (score 1):

Folder spec located in rails root directory in your rails app.
in Rails you can use Rspec generator:

following Gem add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

and then run following command on terminal

```
rails g rspec:install
```

This create folder spec in you project and generate `spec_helper.rb`
And run rspec or bundle exec rspec

Comment: Hi I am facing one problem now, Bundle is install gem is also install now when i run this command "jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:~/rails_project$ rails generate integration test static_pages" error is comming please help me "Could not find generator integration."